# How to Export Data Outside .then() Block (SuperAgent Library)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-modules, superagent

I have two files on my `Nodejs` project that depends on each other. I use a simple library called `SuperAgent` **(I need it)**

[SuperAgent Library Links](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

in `file1.js`

```
const file2 = require('./file2');

let callMe = async (x) => {
  const resData = await file2.getNow(x);
  console.log(resData);
};
callMe('Header Data');
```

while in `file2`

```
const request = require('superagent');

module.exports = {
  getNow: (x) => {
    // Here I use simple SuperAgent
    return request
      .get('https://loremipsum.com')
      .set({
        Header: `${x}`,
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        // I want res to be pass to resData variable on file1
      });
  }
};
```

I want `res` to be pass to `resData` variable on `file1`.

I already tried many different things here, assigning to variable or returning a value, but it doesn't work so far, and `resData` keep giving `undefined` value. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is following example works for you?

file1

```html
const file2 = require('./file2');

let callMe = async (x) => {
  const resData = file2.getNow(x).then(function(resData){
      console.log(resData);
  })
};
callMe('Header Data');
```

file2

```html
const request = require('superagent');

module.exports = {
  getNow: (x) => {
// Here I use simple SuperAgent
return request
  .get('https://loremipsum.com')
  .set({
    Header: `${x}`,
  })
  .then(function (res) {
      // I want res to be pass to resData variable on file1
      return Promise.resolve(res)
  });
  }
};
```